# Blog page = Latest Post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

my client has the following wordpress site =

http://texasdentalimplants.com/index.php/blog

This is how the blog page traditionally works :

**User clicks on Blog Page --> Series of posts are shown --> User chooses to click blog post, user sees chosen blog post**

The client, whoever, wants to only display 1 blog post per page, so now the "blog" page, kind of becomes redundant(It's just an exact copy of the blog post).

What I would like to do is to make it work like this --

**User clicks on "Blog" ---> User sees the latest post --> User can click "previous post" and "next post", to go back and forth.**

How would I make it so that when I click on "Blog", it goes *directly* to the latest blog post?

This is all in an effort to simply reduce redundancy, since the client is worried that it will affect SEO.

Comment: can you clarify a bit for me, your saying when you click next or prev on the latest post it goes to that specific post?

Comment: Hey David, what I'm essentially trying to do is to remove the "blog" page altogether, for right now the blog page only displays 1 post. So, instead of linking to the blog page, I'd like to link to latest post. I'm a little confused myself to be honest, apologies if I'm not being clear.

Comment: are you trying to posts to a specific page? sorry im still trying to get what you want to do exactly

Comment: Hey david, I updated the question to make it a bit more clear. Thanks for staying with me!

Comment: doesnt the blog currently show the lastest post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a poor job of phrasing this question, but what I essentially wanted was to link to the latest post in my navigation. To do this, I followed this tutorial:

http://www.viper007bond.com/2011/09/20/code-snippet-add-a-link-to-latest-post-to-wordpress-nav-menu/

Essentially, I added a link in my navigation with an anchor #latestpost. The code snippet was added in functions.php to replace #latestpost with the link to the latest post